# Why is chess considered special for educating a mindful person?

Tags: learning, gamification, video-games, transfer

I can find countless quotes like this

> In many countries chess is incorporated into the scholastic
>   curriculum. Countless researchers and studies have shown over the
>   years that chess does indeed strengthen a child's mental clarity,
>   fortitude, stability, and overall health. In this technologically
>   driven world, chess helps aid in the synthesis and growth of certain
>   areas in the brain and mind where many children can benefit as they
>   grow older from the game. "It's all condensed in a playful manner in a
>   game format and it's extremely fascinating because first of all I'm in
>   control of my own destiny, I'm in charge. You have to be responsible
>   for your actions, you make a move, you had better think ahead about
>   what's going to happen, not after it happens, because then it's too
>   late. Chess teaches discipline from a very early age. It teaches you
>   to have a plan and to plan ahead. If you do that, you'll be rewarded

These beilefs are so strong that even got [a recognition in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_as_mental_training).

[Here is another quote](http://education.jhu.edu/PD/newhorizons/strategies/topics/thinking-skills/chess/) to highlight the gist of my question

> Chess has a unique and strong brand attribute, in that it is generally
>   perceived that playing chess and being smart are connected.

I do not ask if chess really improve the mental performance. I am asking `Why are they considered unique/unmatched` in this respect? Almost any game demands strengthening your intellect for careful planning of your moves. Why other games are less useful?

Answer (score 3):

Chess is considered "special" due to certain attributes of the game. From "[Beyond the 64 Squares: Does Chess Instruction Enhance Children’s Academic and Cognitive Skills? A Meta-Analysis](http://mindmodeling.org/cogsci2016/papers/0545/index.html)":

> Two main explanations have been adduced to support this hypothesis.
>   First, chess requires decision-making skills and high-level processes
>   (such as acquiring and selecting relevant information from a problem)
>   similar to those used in mathematics and reading (Margulies, 1992).
>   Second, since chess is a demanding task involving focused attention
>   and problem solving, playing chess should strengthen these cognitive
>   abilities and thus be beneficial for children's school performance
>   (Bart, 2014).

However, this consideration is only marginally valid. In "[Enhancing Creativity in Children by Imparting Chess Training](http://mindmodeling.org/cogsci2016/papers/0344/index.html)" the increase in mathematical skills from Chess was compared to mathematical instruction and playing [the game Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)). Although Chess outperformed Go, thus cementing it's "specialness", it did not beat basic mathematical instruction.

In conclusion, Chess is a bit "special" among games in terms of cognitive improvement, however it doesn't beat actually doing a task and it seems unlikely for any other game would be superior.

Comment: +1 But, I cannot concur with the part "it seems unlikely for any other game would be superior". How about simple games? IMO, simple games can go a long way to complement basic mathematical instruction (eg: subtraction games[see Sec. 2 in https://math.uchicago.edu/~ac/cgt.pdf] to encourage kids to learn multiplication), *and may be even used as a way of basic mathematical instruction*.