# Cognitive benefits of learning how to code ?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Since I have learnt to program I seem to be able to structure my personal arguments more logically

I have a few difficult relationships, so it been quite a big help

Has anyone done any research into the cognitive benefits of learning coding,

Or has anyone experience something similar
I would be really interested to know

Thanks

Comment: This is a specific case of a more general question: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/207/7001, https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/15779/7001, https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/15764/7001.  Rather than have a specific question for every possible discipline, especially since the answer is the same across the board, I propose to mark this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg - I'd recommend to vote to close based on being a duplicate, that way it appears in the review queue. Also, it prevents a lone mod-vote, which tends to cause OP to frown upon the mod team now and then.